# Cakephp doesn't work after installing php5-curl package

Tags: cakephp-1.2

I have an android app, it call a function of a web-server (using cakephp). And it return error like this 'call to undefined function curl_init()'.
I do some search on google and try to fix that error by install php5-curl package, but after installing this package, the web-server doesn't work any more. it return

> Strict Standards: Non-static method App::core() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 429
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'file' in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 622
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'line' in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 622
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method App::core() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 429
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 398
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically in /var/www/postmail/cake/basics.php on line 213
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/configure.php on line 155
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 657
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 657
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 668
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 668
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 673
> Warning (2): strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. [CORE/cake/libs/cache.php, line 570]
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 308
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/configure.php on line 155
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method CakeLog::write() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 311
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 311
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method CakeLog::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cake_log.php on line 230
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method App::import() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cake_log.php on line 180
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method App::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/configure.php on line 909
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/configure.php on line 982
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cache.php on line 330
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cache.php on line 505
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/configure.php on line 155
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Inflector::underscore() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cache.php on line 672
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Inflector::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/inflector.php on line 512
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function cd() on a non-object in /var/www/postmail/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248

does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?? I had this same problem but it was a problem between the combination of CakePHP 1.3.6 and PHP 5.4. After updating CakePHP to it's latest version the problem has been resolved.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error if you want to hide these

Comment: What is the lowest stable that we should upgrade to? Will 1.4 or similar? I don't want to go through the headache of upgrading all the way to 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your CakePHP /app/tmp/cache folder is writable. I faced similar issue with CakePHP 1.3 and realized it was due to the cache folder's permission. Hope this helps.

In your terminal, type the following command to allow the CakePHP folder to be writable:-

```
chmod -R 777 /your_root_directory/your_site_name/app/tmp/cache
```

Comment: It seems completely unrelated, by yes, it fixes this issues. Because upgrading CakePHP is sometimes not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Your cakephp version is old, and has problems with the latest version of PHP.

You could try updating your CakePhp version. Seems that your are using the 1.3 version, so update to the latest one.
You could find it

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archives/1.3

Only replacing the **cake/** folder with the new one, you fix this problem

Comment: Only replacing the "cake" folder will break your app, you need to replace bootstrap, index, core and some other changes etc ... Please consider correcting the answer.

Comment: Sorry me, Im trying to understand what do you suggest.
Why do you need to replace bootstrap, index, etc?
Your normal project structure should be:
app-name
/app
/cake
..
/

So you dont change anything on the app/ folder, only the cake one (thats the reason because you'll never need to change the content of /cake)

Comment: Some of the other changes are documented: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Appendices/Mihttp://blog.room34.com/archives/4480grating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3.html, some of them are not but others found them: http://blog.room34.com/archives/4480, I switched 1.2 to 1.3 no so long ago, and it was not as simple as just replacing the cake folder, even if you respect their standards, not get me wrong, it's not hard to do it, but it requires some work (I think it took me about 4 hours when I did it), but still discovered problems in the next days as a result of testing.