# joomla 2.5 'JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file'

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have installed joomla 2.5.4 in my system(window 7 64bit) but when I am trying to upload the package it is showing the error:

> 1.'JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file'.
>
> 2.'Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2.5.4\plugins\system\rokextender\rokextender.php
>   on line 32'
>
> 3.Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2.5.4\plugins\system\rokextender\rokextender.php
>   on line 32
>
> 4.Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2.5.4\plugins\system\rokextender\rokextender.php
>   on line 32

Can anybody help me to fix this error?

Comment: What are you trying to install and could you link to the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a permissions problem (see [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)), and it's specific to the RocketTheme Extender that they use with Gantry for some of their RT *magic*.  I'd check all the permissions in Joomla to make sure they match the minimum requirements, and then check the RocketTheme [Products Forum](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=197&rb_v=viewforum) for anything specific to that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Fulfill the minimal Gantry requirements:

- PHP 5.3 or bigger
- Write rights on you folder.

Set the folder rights to 755.
Remark: You can also set this to 777, but your provider might protect your site from public access. This might generate strange errors, which have nothing to do with Joomla problems.