# Unable to turn off strict standards warnings, XAMMP, PHP 5.4.7

Tags: warnings, php, strict

I'm trying to get some third-party PHP software to run on Windows (it runs on Ubuntu).

I'm using XAMMP with Apache/2.4.3, PHP/5.4.7

The php.ini file, C:\xampp\php\php.ini, is set to not report strict warnings as shown below:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I know that PHP is reading this it's reported as the loaded configuration file in phpinfo() and if I intentionally put an error into it, apache can't restart.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error) has an answer that suggests modifying the root .htaccess as follows:

```
php_value display_errors 0
php_value error_reporting 30719
```

This also had a comment which says that's the .htaccess is the *only* solution that worked for PHP 5.4.7.

However, still no luck. Short of switching to WAMP, is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Perhaps the third-party software resets the error reporting level, overriding your settings?

Comment: This comment on php.net may be relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#98414

Comment: @Jon - I hardcoded "ini_set('display_errors', '0');" in the require command for the class where the first error was coming from and it got rid of all the error message. If you want to post an answer, I'll check it off.

Comment: @JackBeNimble: Glad to help. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this third-party software you mention overrides the error reporting level itself after you and therefore "wins". Check for this and if that's what happens, configure it appropriately or make sure to override the settings last.

Answer (score 4):

I know that some WAMP packages will copy `php.ini` in `C:\Windows`. Run `php -i` and make sure that php is actually using `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. Also remember that starting with PHP 5.4.0, `E_STRICT` became part of `E_ALL`.

Comment: PHP 5.4 change brought me here!