# Squirrelmail ERROR when loading read/new messages

Tags: php, squirrelmail

I was able to successfully install my webmail client; however I keep receiving these errors listed below each time I load a message....has anyone encountered such error before? if so how can I go about resolving it? Thanks in advance!

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Message::parseStructure() should not be called statically in C:\Apache24\htdocs\squirrelmail\functions\mime.php on line 36`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method Message::parseBodyStructure() should not be called statically in C:\Apache24\htdocs\squirrelmail\class\mime\Message.class.php on line 296`

`Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\Apache24\htdocs\squirrelmail\class\mime\Message.class.php on line 367`

`Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\Apache24\htdocs\squirrelmail\class\mime\Message.class.php on line 367`

`Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\squirrelmail\functions\mime.php on line 1594`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `php.ini` to be not strict.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

And restart your apache server.

---

Or even, you can do it in your php code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');     # don't show any errors...
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  # ...but do log them
```

Reference: [PHP 5 disable strict standards error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)