# XAMPP turn off Strict Standards errors

Tags: php, xampp, error-reporting

I am trying to disable Strict Standards from showing up on my screen.

I took a look at my php.ini files and see these lines:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

What do these lines mean and how do I disable the Strict Standards error from showing up?

I also see this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd change this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

to the production Production Value

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

You can also change the display_errors settings which will allow you to log errors, but not display them

```
display_errors = Off
```