# Strict Standards Error After Update Wordpress 3.6

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this error message.

Error 1:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of BBP_Walker_Dropdown::start_el()
>   should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output, $object, $depth =
>   0, $args = Array, $current_object_id = 0) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-content\plugins\bbpress\includes\common\classes.php
>   on line 185

View the source code in here : http://pastebin.com/sMahh0w8

Error 2:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-content\plugins\bbpress\bbpress.php on line
>   845

View the source code in here : http://pastebin.com/5LMpdNcK

Error 3:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-content\plugins\bbpress\includes\users\capabilities.php
>   on line 124

View the source code in here : www.pastebin.com/91gwVkXh

Can someone help me, please!
Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you review this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error

Comment: Thank you so much Matteo for your suggest. 

Disable error reporting is not a good solution. 
I think i must fixed this problems without disable error reporting. Can you help me, please!

Comment: This question is not a coding question. It belongs on the wordpress forums..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

there is a patch available which solves most of the "Strict Standards" errors: http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2371

But this will not solve the "Declaration of BBP_Walker_Dropdown::start_el()" error. You will have to apply the changeset # 5048, too.

Edit: the easiest way is to just download the latest trunk which solves all problems at once: http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/5081/trunk?old_path=%2F&format=zip

Answer (score 0):

The error leads from different incomplete declarations in the extended class - it needs to be changed to match the one as in WP codex.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php#L10

```
start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
```