# Spaw Editor - Strict Standards: Non-static method .... Errors

Tags: php, editor

I recently upgraded to PHP version 5.4 on my servers and immediately saw errors in the content editing area of my admin, all of which appear to be caused by the copy of Spaw Editor PHP Edition version 2.0.8.1 which can be downloaded from http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/en_spaw/en_spaw_download.

Here is a small example of what gets dumped out on my screen when loading areas of the site which contain this editor:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawVars::getServerVar() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/config/config.php on line 7

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::setStaticConfigItem() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/config/config.php on line 7

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::configVar() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/class/config.class.php on line 119

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::getStaticConfigValue() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/config/config.php on line 8

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::getStaticConfigItem() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/class/config.class.php on line 236

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::configVar() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/class/config.class.php on line 143

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::getStaticConfigValue() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/config/config.php on line 9

Strict Standards: Non-static method SpawConfig::getStaticConfigItem() should not be called statically in /home/modusint/canadatravels/modusadm/admin/js/spaw2/class/config.class.php on line 236
```

And it goes on for about 1400 lines of errors  lol

After researching the problem I finally got down to solution posted by Starx that was very closely related to my own problem on this post ([PHP 5 disable strict standards error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)) and the problem cleared right up.  I added these lines of code to spaw.inc.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('error_reporting',30719);
```

With that all my error message have disappeared, but the editor doesn't work properly anymore.

Unfortunately I'm not a very good programmer in the sense that I don't understand anything to do with Object Oriented programming style, I'm an old school C programmer and this style has suited me just fine when doing my own coding in PHP.  Here in is my problem, I cant figure out how to fix this.  The Solmetra website does not appear to be active anymore though I noticed it was updated on http://sourceforge.net/projects/spaw/ as recently as April 17th, 2013 and unfortunately I HAVE to use this product because it's the only editor on the market I can find that possess multilingual tabs which is critical to my business.

Does anyone have any experience with this product or suggestions?

tyvm,

Vince

Comment: You can either downgrade the PHP version, or call the methods normally. I'm not sure, but this kind of error is not fatal and shouldn't stop executing the script, but still, to call methods by their instance, you need to instantiathe the classes i.e. `$SpawVars = new SpawVars();` ; `$SpawVars->getServerVar()`, instead of `$SpawVars::getServerVar()` ... or ... make the methods static. It seems pretty much of code to refactor...

Comment: @Royal Bg Then I guess I need someone to help me fix this product because, old or not, it's interface and method of communicating with my client side code makes it the only product on the market that does what I need it to.  PS: I spoke with the developers of ckeditor about 4 years ago after Spaw halted development and they agreed there was real value in the features I was using and that they would be very useful to have in ckeditor but seems like the conversation was forgotten long ago for more immediate needs.  So I guess I need to hire someone to fix this puppy, any takers?

Comment: FYI to anyone interested in using this product, I emailed the original developer 'Alan Mendelevich' requesting assistance with this problem and he responded with "Unfortunately I haven't touched PHP in more than 5 years and have no idea about what’s going on in that space and don’t even remember what I knew back then. So, I’m sorry, but I won’t be able to help you."