# Print results to a table with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, html-table

I'm using PDO and I'm trying to print the results on a table, but the values don't appear. I need to use the `<td>` tags.

Here is my complete code with a help of francisco:

```
 <?php
    require_once('config.php');


    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, username, email FROM user");
    $stmt->execute();  
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    ?>  


                <table id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>email</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                       foreach ($result as $row): 

                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $row['id'];?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['username'];?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['email'];?></td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: What is your resulting html?

Comment: I'll dig into it, so far, it's `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()` if you want to get every user. Do you have [error handling set to strict and logging them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1248952/938236)? Do that before even including the config.php and see what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `fetchAll()` outside of loop **OR** call `fetch()` in each iteration like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    // do sth
```

If you want foreach, just call `fetchAll()` and do foreach loop over result.