# What is the solution to the error message to put system into server?

Tags: php

When I run my system in the localhost, it is successful. but when I put it into a server, it displays this error message..what is the problem?

```
Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method DOMDocument::loadXML() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in <b>F:\htdocs\bricksmind\hafiz\dochelper.php</b> on line <b>58
```

Below is the line 58 of dochelper.php:

```
$Xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($Data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 5 disable strict standards error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)

Comment: please show what's on line 58 of `dochalper.php`

Comment: @ponciste, I already show the line 58 of dochelper.php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is caused because you are calling the method `loadXML` statically when it is not static.

You can fix this issue this way:

```
// create a DOMDocument instance
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// call the method on the instance
$doc->loadXML($Data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

// then print the XML 
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

hope this helps :-)