# PHP Upgradation issue

Tags: php, version

Recently we have upgraded our PHP version in C-panel to PHP Version 5.4.36. After updation we have run the Easy Apache successfully. After that Some of the websites are getting errors in website. I am giving you some sample examples. Can you please let us know the possibilities and the solutions.

http://www.kopanaacreations.com/bollywood-replica.html 
http://supremelaptopservices.com/

Prompt response will be highly appreciated.
Regards,
Subbareddy

Answer (score 1):

The first one is actually an out of memory error, which means that either the images you have uploaded are too big to be processed by the GD module with your current memory settings or there is another error going on there.

The second site has errors because you have strict errors enabled (they are enabled by default on newer version of PHP)

[Disabling Strict Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)

See the link above on how to rectify this!