# Can't disable Strict Standards errors in Runtime

Tags: php, runtime-error, ini

I want to disable all PHP erros or prevent them to be displayed, but Strict Standard errors insist on showing up.

I'm adding this (though two line are redundant)

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set( "display_errors", 0 );
error_reporting(0);
```

My application is hosted on OpenShift and running PHP 5.4.

**EDIT**

Just realized it's not the only kind of error being thrown. I added a syntax error (omitted a ;) and it showed the error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ...

Comment: You have to checkout where did you have placed the previous code. If you have some code before the above code is regarded, the errors of that code should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248996/1027877

## in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');     # don't show any errors...
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  # ...but do log them
```

You can have this in your htaccess file

```
php_flag display_errors off
```