# Silence "Declaration ... should be compatible" warnings in PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2, php-7.1, php-7.0

After upgrade to PHP 7 the logs almost choked on this kind of errors:

`PHP Warning: Declaration of Example::do($a, $b, $c) should be compatible with ParentOfExample::do($c = null) in Example.php on line 22548`

How do I silence these and only these errors in PHP 7?

- Before PHP 7 they were `E_STRICT` type of warnings [which could be easily dealt with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error). Now they're just plain old warnings. Since I **do** want to know about other warnings, I can't just turn off all warnings altogether.
- I don't have a mental capacity to rewrite these legacy APIs not even mentioning all the software that uses them. Guess what, nobody's going to pay for that too. Neither I develop them in the first place so I'm not the one for blame. (Unit tests? Not in the fashion ten years ago.)
- I would like to avoid [any trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27329541/93540) with `func_get_args` and similar as much as possible.
- Not really I want to downgrade to PHP 5.
- I still want to know about other errors and warnings.

Is there a clean and nice way to accomplish this?

Comment: Those are `Warnings`, not `Errors`. And you should not try to "silence" them, but to solve that issue instead. The purpose of the warning is to tell you that your code will run into issues in future.

Comment: @arkascha it would take days to fix them proper, therefore this question

Comment: @arkascha I rather hope this legacy API will be decommissioned before there will be trouble. But this isn't going to happen for a year or two.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure those comments are really necessary here. True, in an ideal world, you'll have all the time and money to happily fix legacy code. But in the real world, that is all to often not possible or even allowed.

Comment: @arkascha The OP clearly states that this is a suboptimal situation that currently not much can be done about. I totally agree that it can be absolutely unrealistic to reimplement and thereby possibly completely redesign an entire API, when there's currently "no problem" besides a few extra log messages (management's point of view, obviously). This is a legitimate question, no need to be so harsh.

Comment: @Yoshi I absolutely agree and I never said anything else. But that does not change the fact that the situation is what it is and is caused by what I said.

Comment: @arkascha I know, what I try to say is, though you are correct, it's not helping here. ;)

Comment: Please note that I wrote comments, not an answer :-)

Comment: To get to an answer here... a *custom error handler* should allow you the freedom to selectively suppress anything you want; though it would arguably not be as nice a solution as just setting a specific error_reporting flag.

Comment: To add a final comment, I'd say, if the code is not fit for php7 then it should not have to be run in an php7 environment. IMO legacy code unchanged belongs to the environment it was built in.

Comment: @Yoshi sure you're right - it will stay running under PHP5 *in production* while PHP5 is supported and updated; but I got to be prepared for its end of life

Comment: I just want to add that this type of thing is a prime candidate for stronger enforcement in PHP 8. I suggest that whatever you do you keep this in mind.

Comment: @LeviMorrison could you point in a direction where one can read about these new enforcements?

Comment: There isn't anything concrete yet, but if this code used interfaces or abstract classes in the inheritance then it would already be a hard-error. I expect their behavior to be unified in some future version of PHP, possibly PHP 8.

Comment: Really I want to challenge this assumption somewhere. Because PHP already enforces explicitly defined interfaces. And there's `func_get_args()` which enable fluent interfaces anyway.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

#### 1. Workaround

Since it is not always possible to correct all the code *you did not write*, especially the legacy one...

```php
if (PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7) {
    set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
       return strpos($errstr, 'Declaration of') === 0;
    }, E_WARNING);
}
```

This error handler returns `true` for warnings beginning with `Declaration of` which basically tells PHP that a warning was taken care of. That's why PHP won't report this warning elsewhere.

Plus, this code will only run in PHP 7 or higher.

---

If you want this to happen only in regard to a specific codebase, then you could check if a file with an error belongs to that codebase or a library of interest:

```php
if (PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7) {
    set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $file) {
        return strpos($file, 'path/to/legacy/library') !== false &&
            strpos($errstr, 'Declaration of') === 0;
    }, E_WARNING);
}
```

---

#### 2. Proper solution

As for actually fixing someone else's legacy code, there is a number of cases where this could be done between easy and manageable. In examples below class `B` is a subclass of `A`. Note that you do not necessarily will remove any LSP violations by following these examples.

1. Some cases are pretty easy. If in a subclass there's a missing default argument, just add it and move on. E.g. in this case:

   ```
   Declaration of B::foo() should be compatible with A::foo($bar = null)
   ```

   You would do:

   ```
   - public function foo()
   + public function foo($bar = null)
   ```
2. If you have additional constrains added in a subclass, remove them from the definition, while moving inside the function's body.

   ```
   Declaration of B::add(Baz $baz) should be compatible with A::add($n)
   ```

   You may want to use assertions or throw an exception depending on a severity.

   ```
   - public function add(Baz $baz)
   + public function add($baz)
     {
   +     assert($baz instanceof Baz);
   ```

   If you see that the constraints are being used purely for documentation purposes, move them where they belong.

   ```
   - protected function setValue(Baz $baz)
   + /**
   +  * @param Baz $baz
   +  */
   + protected function setValue($baz)
     {
   +     /** @var $baz Baz */
   ```
3. If you subclass has less arguments than a superclass, and you could make them optional in the superclass, just add placeholders in the subclass.     Given error string:

   ```
   Declaration of B::foo($param = '') should be compatible with A::foo($x = 40, $y = '')
   ```

   You would do:

   ```
   - public function foo($param = '')
   + public function foo($param = '', $_ = null)
   ```
4. If you see some arguments made required in a subclass, take the matter in your hands.

   ```
   - protected function foo($bar)
   + protected function foo($bar = null)
     {
   +     if (empty($bar['key'])) {
   +         throw new Exception("Invalid argument");
   +     }
   ```
5. Sometimes it may be easier to alter the superclass method to exclude an optional argument altogether, falling back to `func_get_args` magic. Do not forget to document the missing argument.

   ```
     /**
   +  * @param callable $bar
      */
   - public function getFoo($bar = false)
   + public function getFoo()
     {
   +     if (func_num_args() && $bar = func_get_arg(0)) {
   +         // go on with $bar
   ```

   Sure this can become very tedious if you have to remove more than one argument.
6. Things get much more interesting if you have serious violations of substitution principle. If you do not have typed arguments, then it is easy. Just make all extra arguments optional, then check for their presence. Given error:

   ```
   Declaration of B::save($key, $value) should be compatible with A::save($foo = NULL)
   ```

   You would do:

   ```
   - public function save($key, $value)
   + public function save($key = null, $value = null)
     {
   +     if (func_num_args() < 2) {
   +         throw new Exception("Required argument missing");
   +     }
   ```

   Note that we couldn't use `func_get_args()` here because it does not account for default (non-passed) arguments. We are left with only `func_num_args()`.
7. If you have a whole hierarchies of classes with a diverging interface, it may be easier diverge it even further. Rename a function with conflicting definition in every class. Then add a proxy function in a single intermediary parent for these classes:

   ```
   function save($arg = null) // conforms to the parent
   {
       $args = func_get_args();
       return $this->saveExtra(...$args); // diverged interface
   }
   ```

   This way LSP would still be violated, although without a warning, but you get to keep all type checks you have in subclasses.

Comment: Best answer by far; most of the others assume this is your code, so "you" should correct it. Not all of us are lucky enough to have 100% control over their entire code base, including all libraries. LSP warnings are pretty common in older libs, and forking someone else's legacy lib that has LSP violations in its internal logic, but the exposed API works perfectly well, is a huge amount of extra work for something that could only introduce bugs into a stable codebase.

If this answer could use anything, it would be to check in your top `if` if the error is coming from a specific lib too.

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro I put it as the very first code after the opening <?php tag in an include file used everywhere.

Comment: This doesn't work. The warning is triggered when PHP compiles the template. For some reason, this does not trigger the error handler even though it is registered at the time the file or class is included.

However, the warning is only triggered when the file is first compiled. Once compiled and stored in the opcache, there are no further warnings emitted.

Comment: @WillemStuursma apparently you have some other error handler interfering

Comment: This works for apache but not when i use php via the command line. Any thoughts why cli does not get this error handler?

Comment: @thinkwinwin you have to ask a separate question with your code

Comment: Thank you for giving both the direct answer, and the right answer

Answer (score 25):

For those who want to actually correct your code so it no longer triggers the warning: I found it useful to learn that you can add additional parameters to overridden methods in subclasses as long as you give them default values. So for example, while this will trigger the warning:

```
//"Warning: Declaration of B::foo($arg1) should be compatible with A::foo()"
class B extends A {
    function foo($arg1) {}
}

class A {
    function foo() {}
}
```

This will not:

```
class B extends A {
    function foo($arg1 = null) {}
}

class A {
    function foo() {}
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that, do you have a link to php.net which explain it?

Comment: @MatTheCat I don't remember how I discovered this but it wasn't from any official documentation. However, if you want to read more about it, it's all based on the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) - having a default value of null doesn't violate the LSP because then subclasses don't *require* a different API than the parent class. See my comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840762/560114) below for some more details and links.

Comment: Thanks! I also observed it works whatever the default value is.

Answer (score 21):

If you *must* silence the error, you can declare the class inside a silenced, immediately-invoked function expression:

```
<?php

// unsilenced
class Fooable {
    public function foo($a, $b, $c) {}
}

// silenced
@(function () {
    class ExtendedFooable extends Fooable {
        public function foo($d) {}
    }
})();
```

I would strongly recommend against this, though. It is better to fix your code than to silence warnings about how it is broken.

---

If you need to maintain PHP 5 compatibility, be aware that the above code only works in PHP 7, because [PHP 5 did not have uniform syntax for expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax). To make it work with PHP 5, you would need to assign the function to a variable before invoking it (or make it a named function):

```
$_ = function () {
    class ExtendedFooable extends Fooable {
        public function foo($d) {}
    }
};
@$_();
unset($_);
```

Comment: Is this really a better solution than, you know, actually fixing the root problem? Or even the func_get_args trickery that the OP is so keen to avoid? That said, kudos for actually finding a working solution. It definitely doesn't count as the clean and nice solution he asked for though. A grudging +1 from me.

Comment: It's certainly not a better solution, but it does actually answer the question.

Comment: This is unacceptable because it silences all and every error, not only those I do not want. E.g., `@(function () {constant('nothing');})();`

Comment: @sanmai It silences any errors that occur when the class is defined (but not thereafter), yes. You can write a more complicated solution using a custom error handler if you're worried that your class will produce other warnings.

Comment: [That's what I did in the end.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36196748/93540)

Answer (score 18):

PHP 7 removes the `E_STRICT` error level. Info about this can be found in the [PHP7 compatibility notes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php). You might also want to read [the proposal document](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reclassify_e_strict) where it was discussed while PHP 7 was being developed.

The simple fact is this: The `E_STRICT` notices were introduced a number of versions ago, in an attempt to notify developers that they were using bad practice, but initially without trying to force any changes. However recent versions, and PHP 7 in particular, have become more strict about these things.

The error you're experiencing is a classic case:

You have defined a method in your class that overrides a method of the same name in the parent class, but your override method has a different argument signature.

Most modern programming languages would not actually allow this at all. PHP used to allow developers to get away with stuff like this, but the language is becoming more strict with every version, especially now with PHP 7 -- they went with a new major version number specifically so that they could justify making significant changes that break backward compatibility.

The problem you have is because you've already been ignoring the warning messages. Your question implies that this is the solution you want to continue with, but messages like "strict" and "deprecated" should be treated as an explicit warning that your code is likely to break in future versions. By ignoring them for the past number of years, you have effectively placed yourself in the situation you have now. (I know that's not what you want to hear, and doesn't really help the situation now, but it's important to make it clear)

**There really isn't a work around of the kind you're looking for.** The PHP language is evolving, and if you want to stick with PHP 7 your code will need to evolve too. If you really can't fix the code, then you will either have to suppress all warnings or else live with these warnings cluttering up your logs.

The other thing you need to know if you plan to stick with PHP 7 is that there are a number of other compatibility breaks with this version, including some that are quite subtle. If your code is in a state where it has errors like the one you're reporting, it means that it's probably been around for quite a while, and likely has other issues that will cause you problems in PHP 7. For code like this, I would suggest doing a more thorough audit of the code before committing to PHP 7. If you're not prepared to do that, or not prepared to fix the bugs that are found (and the implication from your question is that you are not), then I'd suggest that PHP 7 is probably an upgrade too far for you.

You do have the option of reverting to PHP 5.6. I know you said you don't want to do that, but as a short-to-medium term solution it will make things easier for you. Frankly, I think it might be your best option.

Comment: Okay I get this is bad. But why they won't ban `func_get_args` since they let you get exactly same behavior with "fluent" interfaces? Why are they forcing users to forfeit clear definitions of interfaces and resort to various cheats? Who's going to benefit from this?

Comment: PHP is moving toward being more strict; it hasn't gone all the way there yet, and probably never will (it's never going to evolve to become a Java or C# kind of language). `func_get_args` is still allowed, although with the introduction of variadic function arguments in PHP 5.6, there are a lot fewer use-cases for it. I don't think it'll be deprecated any time soon, but I also don't think many devs writing code for current PHP versions will be using it very much.

Comment: It's worth adding that some languages (like C#) that do have strict override rules also have rules that allow multiple methods to be defined with the same name but different argument lists. In other words, in C#, your override method wouldn't be seen as an override at all; it would be seen as an entirely different method. PHP doesn't allow this currently (hence the error you're getting), but it's perfectly feasible that something like this might come in with a future version. Not helpful for you now, but an interesting thought.

Comment: Imagine that you're right. How does that answer my question?

Comment: My direct answer to your question was in the middle, where I said *"There really isn't a work around of the kind you're looking for"*. In fact, I see you've provided an answer for yourself where you did manage to find a work-around; well done for that. It's ugly and hacky but you did it. Well done. I still stand by what I said though, particularly about needing to check your code for other possible PHP7 glitches that may not show up with warnings.

Comment: Like I said, this isn't *mine* code in a sense that I didn't write it. Luckily there aren't any other serious glitches so far, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I agree: the example in the first post is bad practice.
Now what if you have that example :

```php
class AnimalData {
        public $shout;
}

class BirdData extends AnimalData {
        public $wingNumber;
}

class DogData extends AnimalData {
        public $legNumber;
}

class AnimalManager {
        public static function displayProperties(AnimalData $animal) {
                var_dump($animal->shout);
        }
}

class BirdManager extends AnimalManager {
        public static function displayProperties(BirdData $bird) {
                self::displayProperties($bird);
                var_dump($bird->wingNumber);
        }
}

class DogManager extends AnimalManager {
        public static function displayProperties(DogData $dog) {
                self::displayProperties($dog);
                var_dump($dog->legNumber);
        }
}
```

I believe this is a legitimate code structure, nevertheless this will raise a warning in my logs because the `displayProperties()` do not have the same parameters. Moreover I can't make them optional by adding a `= null` after them...

Am I right thinking this warning is wrong in this specific example please?

Comment: This is the exact problem I'm facing. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No I haven't. I started hiding those warnings but then I had a segmentation fault with PHP7 on a script that has been running for 5 years without one issue on PHP5 and I figured out that maybe PHP7 was not ready yet... I'll give it a try later...

Comment: Actually this code violates the Liskov Substitution Principle and is not supported in almost any OOP language, because then instances of `BirdManager` and `DogManager` could no longer be safely used anywhere that `AnimalManager` can be used, and also can't be type-checked at compile time (since any time you have an `AnimalManager` type hint, you could actually be dealing with one of its subclasses). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle for more details.

Comment: However, there is a legitimate use case that satisfies the LSP but isn't currently supported in PHP: contravariant parameter types - the reverse of your example (contravariant means the parameter type in the subclass is more generic than the parameter type in the parent class). This is due to implementation challenges, but it is mentioned in this [RFP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types#future_work)). See also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72208

Comment: The selected answer appears to cover this situation. Changing your method to accept any AnimalData in your child classes should prevent the warning. `class BirdManager extends AnimalManager {
    public static function displayProperties(AnimalData $bird) { 
        assert($bird instanceof BirdData);...`

Comment: It does indeed @ShaunCockerill, thanks. And thank you sanmai for the thorough answer !
For the moment being, I just hide the warning - lazy bunny - but I will use the assert method instead eventually.
As for the segmentation faults, they are gone. I believe my installation was to be blamed or else the issue would have been slightly more popular... So yay PHP 7 !

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well. I have a class that overrides a function of the parent class, but the override has different num of parameters.  I can think of a few easy work arounds - but do require minor code change.

1. change the name of the function in the subclass (so it no longer overrides parent function)
   -or-
2. change the parameters of the parent function, but make the extra parameters optional (e.g., function func($var1, $var2=null)  - this may be easiest and require less code changes.  But it may not be worth to change this in the parent if its used so many other places.  So I went with #1 in my case.
3. If possible, instead of passing the extra params in the subclass function, use global to pull in the extra params.  This is not ideal coding; but a possible band-aid anyway.

Comment: Thanks @AeonTrek. The problem I'm facing is that the simple snippet I wrote above is actually part of far bigger picture in my application where having the same function names, the same parameters (...) allows me to factorise my code extensively. I appreciate your suggestions but - and with all due respect - they are work arounds, no real answers to the problem. I'm feeling only the PHP community can address my problem unfortunately. Which is why I'm back to PHP5 for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the parent class method definition altogether and intercept it with a magic method.

```php
public function __call($name, $args)
{
    if($name == 'do') {
        // do things with the unknown # of args
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Unknown method $name", 500);
    }
}
```

I just ran into this problem and went this route

Answer (score 0):

If the base class has fewer arguments than the derived class, it is possible to add additional argument(s) to the derived class like this:

```
    $namespace = 'default';
    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        $namespace = func_get_arg(2);
    }
```

In this way, you add a 3rd "defaulted" argument, but do not change the signature.
I would only suggest this if you have a substantial amount of code that calls this and are unable to change that code, and want to maintain backward compatibility.

I found this situation in some old Joomla code (v1.5) where JSession::set added a $namespace param, but has JObject as a base class, where JObject::set has no such parameter.