# PHP7 no STRICT mode?

Tags: php, typo3, php-7, typo3-7.6.x

In my TYPO3 Project is a Extension with a PHP7 Error.

> PHP Warning: Declaration of … should be compatible with …..
>
> 1: PHP Warning: Declaration of tx_caretaker_pi_singleview::getNodeChart($node) should be compatible
>   with tx_caretaker_pibase::getNodeChart() in
>   /typo3conf/ext/caretaker/pi_singleview/class.tx_caretaker_pi_singleview.php
>   line 40

```
class tx_caretaker_pi_singleview extends tx_caretaker_pibase
    {
```

https://github.com/TYPO3-Caretaker/caretaker/blob/master/pi_singleview/class.tx_caretaker_pi_singleview.php

The Problem is the PHP7.1 Strict-Mode ?!

I have 2 Options, i Fix the PHP Problem, or i can change the Mode?
Thanks for Help!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079651/silence-declaration-should-be-compatible-warnings-in-php-7

Answer (score 0):

You can disable warnings in PHP but best would be to let the author fix the issue. You created already an issue at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82513, so all is fine.

Comment: how can i disable the PHP warnings? :)

Comment: $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['displayErrors']
New value = 0

Oops, an error occurred!

PHP Warning: Declaration of tx_caretaker_pi_singleview::getNodeChart($node) should be compatible with tx_caretaker_pibase::getNodeChart() in /typo3conf/ext/caretaker/pi_singleview/class.tx_caretaker_pi_singleview.php line 40