# Actualizar SugarCRM

Tags: php, crm, centos7, sugarcrm

I cannot update `SUGARCRM`, I want to move from version `6.5` to `7`. When I enter Update Wizards, I check the system and do it satisfactorily, but then at the time of uploading the file (second step), I do not see anything. I see the blank screen.

Activated the configuration from `php.ini` for errors and it says

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of ListViewPackages::display() should be compatible with ListViewSmarty::display($end = true) in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/ModuleInstall/PackageManager/ListViewPackages.phpon line 39

Strict Standards: Declaration of ListViewPackages::setup() should be compatible with ListViewDisplay::setup($seed, $file, $where, $params = Array, $offset = 0, $limit = -1, $filter_fields = Array, $id_field = 'id') in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/ModuleInstall/PackageManager/ListViewPackages.phpon line 39

Strict Standards: Non-static method LogicHook::initialize() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils.php on line 2977

Strict Standards: Non-static method Tracker::logPage() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils.php on line 2988

Strict Standards: Non-static method SugarConfig::getInstance() should not be called statically in /home/demosp/public_html/actavindus/include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php on line 362
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Please post your questions in english or use the spanish version https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 5 disable strict standards error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)